# What are the main interpretations offered so far of biscuit conditionals?

Tags: logic, reference-request, linguistics

So-called *biscuit conditionals* are conditionals such as "*There are biscuits, if you want*".

First noticed and discussed by John Langshaw Austin in 1956, biscuit conditionals have been extensively investigated by academics since 1961 and seem to still be the object of intense discussions.

As Austin observed, if a biscuit conditional was taken at face value, it would make no logical sense, and yet we all use them all the time, without apparently even noticing their oddity.

What are the main interpretations offered so far of biscuit conditionals?

Thank you for any scholarly reference.

Comment: My intuitive reaction is to think the biscuit conditional is shorthand for something more like "There are biscuits; you can have one if you want." I wonder if biscuit conditionals take the same form in many other languages.

Comment: @TKol Same thing in French.

Comment: [Siegel](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25001990) discusses semantic interpretations: 1) "if" applies to illocutionary acts rather than to content; 2) there is implicit existential quantification over potential literal acts. [Franke](https://michael-franke.github.io/heimseite/Papers/AC07_Paper.pdf) reduces them to pragmatics: biscuit conditionals are not conditionals at all despite the surface grammar, and serve to shift context for better understanding.

Comment: Perhaps more ambiguous "You can close the door if you're cold".

Comment: @TKoL Perhaps also something like "There are biscuits; and if you want some, then this information is relevant." (and if you don't want biscuits, then it's irrelevant whether there are biscuits or not, although obviously yes, there are still biscuits.)

Answer (score 8):

As you mention, the term 'biscuit conditional' derives from John Austin's example from *How to do Things with Words* (Oxford, 1962).

```
There are biscuits on the sideboard, if you want some.
```

This appears strange for several reasons.

1. It rather invites the quip, Where are the biscuits if I don't want them?
2. It does not imply its contrapositive. If the biscuits are not on the sideboard, you don't want them.
3. The obvious contradictory is, “No there aren’t”. In other words, "If A then B" is contradicted by "not B" rather than by "It is not the case that if A then B" nor by "If A then not B" as would be more common.
4. The truth or probability of the consequent is not dependent upon the truth or probability of the antecedent.

Conditionals like this are quite common. Some other examples might be:

```
If you are interested, there is a wildlife documentary just starting on TV. 
If anybody wants to speak to me, I shall be back in the office tomorrow. 
If anyone asks, we didn't have this conversation. 
If this bird is a canary, it isn't yellow. 
If John loves Mary, he has a strange way of showing it. 
If Alice ate those mushrooms, they did her no harm. 
If there is a conspiracy, I am not part of it.
```

A fairly common way to describe what is going on with these is to say that the antecedent is required for the consequent to be relevant to the conversation. To say apropos of nothing, "There are biscuits on the sideboard," seems to be just an unmotivated observation. Including the antecedent, "if you want some..." helps to make the consequent relevant. The same is true of a great many examples.

We can generalise this approach by appeal to Paul Grice's theory of conversational implicatures. Grice proposes a series of maxims that make up [the co-operative principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle), which forms part of the pragmatics of communication.

We can say that these odd conditionals are ones in which the antecedent is not serving to conditionalise on the truth of the consequent, but is serving to prevent the unconditional assertion of the consequent from violating one of the maxims. In many cases, the appropriate maxim is *Be relevant*, which is why a lot of the examples involve relevance. But other maxims can play a part too. For example:

```
If I remember rightly, the capital of Kazakhstan is Astana.
```

The capital of Kazakhstan is Astana whether I remember rightly or not. But to say unconditionally, "The capital of Kazakhstan is Astana" implies I know this to be the case. The antecedent serves to alert the audience to the fact I am not sure. It prevents the unconditional consequent from violating the maxim, *Do not say that for which you lack adequate evidence*.

```
If you don't mind me saying so, you look terrible.
```

Again, you look terrible whether you mind me saying it or not. Here the unconditional assertion of the consequent would be rude, and the antecedent is serving the pragmatic purpose of making it rather less rude. Geoffrey Leech argues that *Be polite* is a pragmatic maxim, though it is not one of Grice's.

- Paul Grice, "Logic and Conversation" in *Studies in the Ways of Words*. (Harvard, 1989).
- Keith DeRose and Richard E. Grandy, (1999), "Conditional Assertions and 'Biscuit' Conditionals", Noûs, Vol. 33, No. 3, pp. 405-420.
- Stefano Predelli, (2009) "Towards a Semantics for Biscuit Conditionals". Philosophical Studies, Vol. 142, No. 3, pp. 293-305.
- Robyn Carston, *Thoughts and Utterances*. (Blackwell, 2002). Chapter 2.
- Billy Clark, *Relevance Theory*. (Cambridge, 2013). Chapter 2.
- Geoffrey Leech. *Principles of Pragmatics*. (Longman Group, 1983).

Comment: In a context where there are biscuits on the sideboard, the contrapositive *"If the biscuits are not on the sideboard, you don't want them."* is tautologically true, so I wouldn't say it's "not implied".

Comment: *"If anyone asks, we didn't have this conversation."* is usually said in a context where we did have the conversation, and it's only if anyone asks that we should behave and answer as if we didn't, so it seems pretty logical to me.

Comment: Likewisefor the last three: *"If John loves Mary, he has a strange way of showing it. 
If Alice ate those mushrooms, they did her no harm. 
If there is a conspiracy, I am not part of it."*; I don't see what's "biscuit" about them. They seem like straightforward conditionals to me.

Comment: The contrapositive of the biscuit conditional is only tautological if it is interpreted as a material conditional, and I don't see a good reason to interpret it that way.

Comment: The "we didn't have this conversation" one is indeed presumably a falsehood, but the point is that the conversation happened whether anyone asks or not, so the consequent is not conditional upon the truth of the antecedent. It could be glossed as a conditional command, "If anyone asks, pretend we didn't have this conversation."

Comment: The contrapositive of "If Alice ate those mushrooms they did her no harm" is "If eating those mushrooms harmed Alice then she didn't eat them", which doesn't make much sense. Maybe it can be sorted out with some analysis. Potentially it could be understood as an 'even if' - Alice suffered no harm whether she ate the mushrooms or not.

Comment: 1) Either Alice ate those mushrooms or she did not eat those mushrooms. 2) People who eat these mushrooms often, but not always, suffer harm. 3) I notice that Alice is currently not suffering. 4) Conclusion: If Alice ate those mushrooms, they did her no harm. Seems perfectly logical to me.

Comment: A possible way to express the contrapositive is "If eating these mushrooms would harm her, then she did not eat them". Another possible way: "If the person who ate these mushrooms were harmed, then it's not Alice". Yet another: "Either Alice did not eat the mushrooms, or she ate the mushrooms but wasn't harmed." The expression you chose, "If eating these mushrooms harmed her then she did not eat them" is vacuously true although an uncommon choice of words.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152254/discussion-between-bumble-and-stef).

Comment: @Bumble Your answer is excellent as always but what doesn't seem to come out is that there is no consensus in the academic literature on what would be a logical account of them. What you present as "*a fairly common way to describe what is going on*" is on the face of it not a logical account. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Biscuit conditionals are mainly pragmatic in nature, which is to say understanding them depends on the context, what the speaker is intending to convey, what the audience could reasonably be expected to understand, etc. They still have a logic to them. Typically, the consequent is simply unconditionally true, so the logic is straightforward. But the antecedent is doing some pragmatic work in making the utterance appropriate to the context.

Comment: @Bumble "*Typically, the consequent is simply unconditionally true, so the logic is straightforward.*" Alright, but then, why don't you say that in your answer? I think Austin  himself commented that if taken at face value, these conditionals don't make any logical sense. You can't both be right.